# Flutter, how to reduce repeated widget

Tags: function, flutter, widget, dart-2

Thank you for aiding me.

What I'm trying to do is cut down on repeat of the code below;

```
 class PeddingRadius extends StatelessWidget {
  PeddingRadius(final column);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          shadowColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
          elevation: 5,
          child: //my code
     ),
    )
  }
}
```

Is there a way I could make above a function or method and insert the code below?

```
                  Image.asset(
                  'asset/images/HelloWorld.png', height: 100.0, width: 100.0,
                  ),
                  Text('Hello World, form Dart'),
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a child property to the `PeddingRadius`.

```dart
class PeddingRadius extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  PeddingRadius({@required Widget child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          shadowColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
          elevation: 5,
          child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And then give it what ever child you desire.

```dart
PeddingRadius(
  child: Column(
    children: [
       Image.asset(
         assetLocation, height: 100.0, width: 100.0,
       ),
       Text(text),
    ],
  ),
)
// or
PeddingRadius(
  child: RaisedButton(child: Text("Hello World")),
)
```

This is basically the same as @dkap's answer with an own widget class and a little bit more reusability since it accepts all kinds of children.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a function to return your code as a Widget

```
Widget myWidget(String assetLocation, String text) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          shadowColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
          elevation: 5,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                assetLocation, height: 100.0, width: 100.0,
              ),
              Text(text),
            ],
          )
      ),
    );
  }
```

then just use `myWidget('asset/images/HelloWorld.png', 'Hello World, form Dart')`